# Error while adding a subscriber in a publication list

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

**SOAP Request ::**

```
<soap:Body>
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"
        xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
        <Options>
            <SaveOptions>
                <SaveOption>
                    <PropertyName>*</PropertyName>
                    <SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>
                </SaveOption>
            </SaveOptions>
        </Options>
        <Objects xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:type="Subscriber">
            <Client>
                <PartnerClientKey>xxxxxxx</PartnerClientKey>
            </Client>
                <emailaddress>xxx@xxx.com</emailaddress>
                <subscriberkey>xxxxxxx</subscriberkey>
                <lists>
                    <partnerkey xsi:nil="true"></partnerkey>
                    <id>xxxxxxx</id>
                    <objectid xsi:nil="true"></objectid>
                    <status>Active</status>
                </lists>
                <status>Active</status>
        </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

**Response Envelope ::**

```
<soap:Body>
  <CreateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <Results>
        <StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
        <StatusMessage>InvalidEmailAddress</StatusMessage>
        <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
        <ErrorCode>12000</ErrorCode>
        <NewID>0</NewID>
        <Object xsi:type="Subscriber">
           <Client>
              <ID>xxxxxxxx</ID>
              <PartnerClientKey>xxxx</PartnerClientKey>
           </Client>
           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
           <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        </Object>
     </Results>
     <RequestID>xxxxxx</RequestID>
     <OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
  </CreateResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

I can verify that the email address in question is perfectly valid. 
I cant tell the actual cause of the error.
Thank you for helping me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's complaining because XML (and therefore SOAP) is case sensitive.  "emailaddress" should be "EmailAddress".  Your emailaddress key just happens to be first so it's throwing the error there.  [Here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_subscriber/) is the full example:

```
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true">
            </ObjectID>
            <EmailAddress>help@example.com</EmailAddress>
            <Lists>
                <ID>123</ID>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true">
                </ObjectID>
            </Lists>
            <Attributes>
                <Name>First Name</Name>
                <Value>Lee</Value>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <Name>Last Name</Name>
                <Value>Cruz</Value>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <Name>Company</Name>
                <Value>Northern Trail Outfitters</Value>
            </Attributes>
        </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did correct the email field and subscriberkey field. however when I make this call, it only creates a subscriber but does not add the subscriber to the list mentioned in the request call. My only purpose is to add a subscriber in a given publication list with a given subscribe status. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you make your list keys case-sensitive as well?  ie. <Lists><ID>...